# Microsoft Excel/Google Sheets - Update Adherence

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I would like to produce a result wherein it checks if an update is done within 3 hours, it would be pass. If it goes beyond 3 hours, then it would be a fail. So this is how my raw data looks like:

[image: Raw Data]

Then I would like the results to be like this:

[image: Output]

Currently having a hard time in figuring out the formula for this to produce the output. If there's a better way to show output, then I'm willing to try.

EDIT: Just want to add, updates are done in a manner that it is not organized. For example, ID AB1 is spread out on all the rows (e.g. 1st update is on row 2, 2nd update is on row 5, 3rd update is on row 14, etc.)

[image: Edit]

Answer (score 1):

Okay so in column E you'll calculate the row offset to the next occurance of the current row's ID. In column F you'll calculate the difference in hours (starting in E2 and F2)

```
E2 =MATCH(A2, A3:A$1001,0)
F2 =IF(D2="Done", 10000, IF(ISNUMBER(E2), INDEX(B3:B$1001,E2)+INDEX(C3:C$1001,E2)-(B2+C2),10000))
```

We will return a disproportionately large number e.g. 10000 for the first ID of its kind, or if an ID hasn't logged a "done" yet.

Now for counting total updates:

```
=COUNTIFS(LEFT(A2:A1000,2),"AB",D2:D1000,"Ongoing")
```

and for counting updates within 3 hours

```
=COUNTIFS(LEFT(A2:A1000,2),"AB",F2:F1000,"<=3")
```

NB: because we use LEFT on an array larger than one cell, we need to tell Excel to calculate using array formulas by finishing the formula by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: What if the updates are done in a manner that it is not organized in my raw data? For example, ID AB1 is spread out on all the rows (e.g.1st update is on row 2, 2nd update is on row 5, 3rd update is on row 14, etc.)

Comment: Could you not just add a filter to the header then sort by id?

Comment: The thing is, this is done in google sheets. The user can keep adding unlimited updates until the status is done. So if ever there's a way to automate the time difference between the two updates even though they're not adjacent rows, that would be good.

Comment: Right makes sense. So is it at least always in chronological order? Or at least AB1 will have in order ongoing, ongoing..., done (with other user's data interspersed)? If there's a new AB1 after the last "done", it is basically a new call / transaction?

Comment: Updated but untested. Let me know if it works by accepting the solution